# Node.js level(api key) based rate limit

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have spent the last hour trying to look for a solution to rate limit my api.

I want to limit a path `/users` for example. But most rate limits work on 1 rate limit for everyone. I want to use api keys that can be generated by a user. People can generate free api let's say 1000 requests per day. Then if they pay some money they can get 5000 requests per day.

I would like to store these api keys in a mysql database.

Does anyone have any solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to structure your project would be:

user_keys table, includes the api key, the user, time of creation and number of uses so far.
When a user tries to generate a key, check that one doesn't exist yet, and add it to the DB.

When a request arrives, check if the key exists, if it does, do the following:

1: if it has been 24 hours since creation date, set number of uses to 0
2: increment the uses count

if you find the API key and it's at 1k the user reached his limit.

This is a basic implementation, and isn't very efficient, you'll want to cache the API keys in memory, either just in a hashmap in nodejs or using memcached/redis. But, get it working first before trying to optimize it.

EDIT: some code examples

```js
//overly simple in memory cache
const apiKeys = {}

//one day's worth in milliseconds, used later on
const oneDayTime = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

//function to generate new API keys
function generateKey(user) {
  if (apiKeys[user]) {
    throw Error("user already has a key")
  }
  let key = makeRandomHash(); // just some function that creates a random string like "H#4/&DA23#$X/"

  //share object so it can be reached by either key or user
  //terrible idea, but when you save this in mysql you can just do a normal search query
  apiKeys[user] = {
    key: key,
    user: user,
    checked: Date.Now(),
    uses: 0
  }
  apiKeys[key] = apiKeys[user]
}

// a function that does all the key verification for us
function isValid(key) {
  //check if key even exists first
  if (!apiKeys[key]) throw Error("invalid key")

  //if it's been a whole day since it was last checked, reset its uses
  if (Date.now() - apiKeys[key].checked >= oneDayTime) {
    apiKeys[key].uses = 0
    apiKeys[key].checked = Date.now()
  }

  //check if the user limit cap is reached
  if (apiKeys[key].uses >= 1000) throw error("User daily qouta reached");

  //increment the user's count and exit the function without errors
  apiKeys[key].uses++;
}

//express middleware function
function limiter(req, res, next) {
  try {
    // get the API key, can be anywhere, part of json or in the header or even get query
    let key = req.body["api_key"]
    // if key is not valid, it will error out
    isValid(key)
    // pass on to the next function if there were no errors
    next()
  } catch (e) {
    req.send(e)
  }
}
```

this is an overly simplified implementation of a simpler idea, but I hope it gets the idea across.

the main thing you want to change here is how the API keys are saved and retrieved

Comment: Thank you for helping with my question

Comment: Code would help but maybe someone might give a better one. However what would I use to generate an api key I was thinking jwt but I think it would be better to pass the api key every request

Comment: if you use JWT, you won't need an API key, you can just use the user itself as the key, but you will have to change a few things in the snippet